# Identifying which singlepart non-overlapping polygons are islands using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is there a simple method to select singlepart non-overlapping polygons in a single feature-class which are not contiguous with other polygons ie they are island polygons?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain details on whether your "island" geometries are single-part or multi-part (it significantly alters the question).

Comment: @PolyGeo perhaps this question could be merged with its duplicate so that we collect the answers in a single place?

Comment: @Chrisw I don't think these two Q&As should be classed as exact duplicates (so not merged) because the case here, where the polygons may touch but do not overlap, has simpler solutions.  Making them duplicates would mean (I think) that the answer from FelixIP would not apply to the overlapping case.  I'm going to edit their titles to reflect that.

Comment: @PolyGeo The overlap discussion at that other question relates to the method of selecting the polygons with buffers, not the polygons themselves or that identical polygons may be stacked. I agree the wording is unclear (which is why I'd requested an image), but it's the other, non-isolated polygons which may share borders or overlap. I believe both questions seek to identify the same types of polygons - singles that do not in any way touch another. Felix's solution would work there, with an added benefit of at least visually flagging those that *appear* isolated but aren't.

Comment: @ChrisW You may be right.  I've not tested before making my comment above.  However, before considering a merge of this Q&A with http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94979/selecting-isolated-polygons-which-are-not-donuts-but-may-overlap-using-arcgis-de I think we should endeavour to bring all the answers to the standard of FelixIP's and to extend that one to show what happens when an overlapping polygon is introduced to the input.

Comment: @PolyGeo Something I failed to notice earlier was the other question has a 9.3 version restriction - so maybe they shouldn't be merged (though I do think your title edit there might have changed the question). radouxju's answer there mentioned that at 10 and above the solution is polygon neighbors, as you have answered here. Be they just overlapping or entirely coincident and stacked, Felix's method would return a join count other than 1. The key, as I tried to explain in my answer at that other question, is the match_option/select relationship chosen.

Comment: @ChrisW Polygon Neighbors has a version restriction - it was [new at 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Analysis_toolbox/016w0000003z000000/) but, in any event, even if a question specifies the version being used (which I think it always should), I think answers that relate to later versions (and improved ways of doing things) should be encouraged, as long as they specify the version from which they apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested but to do this I would try these steps:

1. [Polygon Neighbors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000045000000) to create a table of polygon neighbors - islands should have no records in this table
2. Use a join between the feature IDs in the feature class and the neighbors table to select any that match - these are not islands
3. Switch selections in the feature class

Answer (score 7):

Spatial join to itself:

[image]

ORIGINAL POLYGONS:

[image]

JOINED POLYGONS:

[image]