# delete unconnected polygons in a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

I need to delete isolated polygon (green circle) from a shapefile but I do not want to delete polygon that connected with other polygon (red circle?

[image]

Comment: Thank you Richard your answer is very useful. Selecting polygon by area is good but what if the polygons have same area and I want to delete some of them?  Most important for me is how to connect two polygons that linked by 1 virtex? see red circle.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152554/identifying-which-singlepart-polygons-are-islands-using-arcgis-for-desktop/152664#152664

Comment: If the "Most important [thing] for [you] is how to connect two polygons that [are] linked by 1 v[e]rtex" then I recommend that you research/ask that as a separate question.

Comment: polyGeo thank you for corrections. it is very useful.

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions despite that no one of them worked with me, alternatively I deleted unconnected polygon manually and it took longer time to accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles should be converted to file geodatabases for performance and precision and for many options not available with shapefiles.  One of the benefits of converting a shapefile to a feature class in a file geodatabase is that you get an automatically calculated area and perimeter length field for your polygons (length for polylines).  If you keep it as a shapefile you need to create and calculate the area field yourself.  Add a double field and use the geometry calculator to calculate the area of each polygon.  If this is one multi-part polygon then you need to use the [Explode tool on the Editing toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000002000000) or the Multipart to Singlepart tool under the Features toolset of the Data Management toolbox.

Then determine the smallest area you want to keep and select for areas smaller than that with the Select by Attributes tool.

Edit:

I still believe this contributes nothing to accuracy, but here is what I would do to achieve what you want.  First of all one vertex makes no difference to me.  A small buffer of .0005 meters is good enough even if it includes polygons that do not touch each other at all.

1. Buffer all polygons by .0005. with Dissolve type ALL.
2. Use the Singlepart to Multipart tool
3. Use the Spatial Join tool with the One to Many option with the original polygons as the target and the multipart buffers as the target.
4. Dissolve the Spatial Join output on the JoinFID field.
5. Select everything larger than the minimum size you want to allow and export it to get rid of all small irrelevant polygons.

The final output will join together everything within .001 meters of each other that meets whatever minimum area polygon size you choose to allow.  That is more than close enough to actually touching polygons by one vertex given the inherent limitations of what factors you can model for the future projected shoreline.

Comment: Thank you Richard your answer is very useful. Selecting polygon by area is good but what if the polygons have same area and I want to delete some of them? Most important for me is how to connect two polygons that linked by 1 virtex? see red circle. –  Nawaf 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: I don't know how many polygons you have or how large you want them to be as a threshhold, but if you select one of the large polygons and then select by location the layer against itself, then you can select and merge all of the smaller polygons that touched it by one vertex into one shape.  If there are hundreds of these to deal with then you need to explain the rules better for an automated approach.  For example, do any attributes come into play?  What is the smallest area you would allow?  This is a rather inconvenient rule, so why is it important for these shapes?  What do they represent?

Comment: The polygons produced from raster and attribute table include only length and area making the mission so hard. There are so many polygons and I want to merge (join or dissolve) the polygons that connected by 1 vertix. I try to mapp the flood when seal level rise 1 meter, actually I did this by DEM raster (algebra), then converted cells of raster to polygon to calculate area. the polygons represent the inundated area by water. However, my  friend advice me to join cell pixel of raster first and then convert raster to polygon I do not know if it is work.

Comment: Given that this data represents a speculative future condition it sounds like the refinement you want to do will contribute nothing the to the real accuracy of the area you report.  This run is at best within a possible range of outcomes and from the sound of it a fairly optimistic outcome.  It does not sound like your analysis accounts for effects of loss of vegetation, soil composition and saturation, or the hydrodynamic changes that would all affect the shoreline's new equilibrium state. Please tell me the area of small polys relative to the area of all polys to see if they even matter.

Comment: small polygon area is 600 sq. meter and the other polygons  ranging from 700 to 2000 sq. meter.

Comment: I am confused by your answer.  Are those numbers the summary values?  Why is there a range of the larger polygons?  There can only be one number for the large polygons total area if you gave a number for the small polygons total area.  I want the sum total area of small polygons and the sum total area of all polygons, including the small polygons.  Use the Statistics context menu option on the area column with just the small polygons selected and then all polygons selected.  Also tell me the area of the largest small polygon you allowed.  After that I can go over the techniques I would use.

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions despite that no one of them worked with me, alternatively I deleted unconnected polygon manually and took long time to accomplished.